# filter the result of sql with time line

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to select data based on date and time. I have two criteria. How can I implement this?

1. Select the data between 1-1-2013 and 1-10-2013 with time rage
   between 10:00 to 16:00
2. Select the data between 1-1-2013 and 1-10-2013 with
   time range between 20:00 to 08:00 the next morning

I implemented a code. It's only working for first criteria. Here is that code:

```
where date >= '1-1-2013' 
and date < '1-10-2013' 
and cast(date as time) between '10:00' and '16:00'
```

Here the date field in the table is `datetime` type. Please help to solve this.

Comment: Which implementation of SQL are you using?

Comment: Also, it is not clear what ouput you are expecting. Should this query return a single result set containing records matching both conditions?

Comment: sorry i didnt get you.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, SQL Server, etc?

Comment: i know about the first condition. so would be great to get the result with second conditon. and the result should be data which is present between 20hr to 8 hrs next day.

Comment: im using sql server 2008

Comment: Do you require data from `1-11-2013 08:00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using bunch of ORs:

```
select *
from your_table
where date >= '2013-01-01'
    and date < '2013-01-11'
    and (
        cast(date as time) between '10:00' and '16:00'
        or cast(date as time) >= '20:00'
        or cast(date as time) <= '08:00'
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  select * from your_table 
  where  date >='2013-01-01' and date <= '2013-01-11' 
  and convert(varchar,date,8)>'10:00' and convert(varchar,date,8)<'16:00'
```